# Does anyone have any experience using libraries to generate HTML from Objective C on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c

I need to generate some html from within an iPhone application.  Do you have any recommendations on templating libraries to use?  A simple Google search is turning up surprisingly empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MGTemplateEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/05/20/mgtemplateengine-templates-with-cocoa) seems to be a good example of what I'm talking about.

From the blog:

> MGTemplateEngine is a native Cocoa
>   system for generating text output
>   based on templates and data. It’s a
>   close cousin of systems like Smarty,
>   FreeMarker, Django’s template
>   language, and so on.
>
> It’s ideal for Cocoa apps needing to
>   generate text output using
>   variable-substitution (with looping
>   and/or conditional logic), including
>   creating HTML pages (or for apps with
>   WebKit-based UIs), generating invoices
>   or other printable templates, mail
>   merge, data export or any number of
>   other things. It’s also great (in
>   combination with WebKit) for letting
>   your users create themes/styles for
>   your application.

Are there others that people recommend?